# urls don't work with linkify.js

Tags: javascript, linkify

I am trying to use linkify.js library to convert any urls in the text to hyperlinks. The returned string does not come back with hyperlinks and I don't see any errors either.
Please find the code below and advise why this is not working. Thanks.

```
npm install linkifyjs

var linkify = require('linkifyjs');
var linkifyHtml = require('linkifyjs/html');
require('linkifyjs/plugins/hashtag')(linkify); // optional


var testStr = 'http://google.com. This is awesome.';
linkifyHtml(testStr, {
  defaultProtocol: 'https'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var linkified = linkifyHtml(testStr, {
  defaultProtocol: 'https'
});

console.log(linkified);
```

gives me

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="linkified" target="_blank">http://google.com</a>. This is awesome.
```

Comment: Oh! I just had to assign it to a variable. Sorry to bother you on this. Is there a way to get the hyperlink on the description instead of html.